# boss_db:save_record not working with PostgreSQL adapter

Tags: chicagoboss

I'm trying to save a BossRecord to the database using pgsql adapter, of this way:

```
boss_db:save_record(admins:new("admins-1", 1)).
```

In ChicagoBoss's shell this returns:

```
{ok,{admins,"admins-1",1}}
```

But the record is not actually being saved in the database.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE admins("
        "ID integer primary key,"
        "user_ID integer"
    ")
```

My model:

```
-module(admins, [Id, UserId]).
-compile(export_all).
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Evan Miller I've found the solution, like here he says [evan miller ChicagoBoss blog](http://reg.dorogaved.ru/com/blog3/blog_boss.html#backend) "the Id field of each model is assumed to be an integer supplied by the database (e.g., a SERIAL type in Postgres)... specifying an Id value other than the atom 'id' for a new record will result in an error"

So I changed my table to:

```
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admins("
            "ID serial primary key,"
            "user_ID integer"
        ")"
```

And also change the model (to specify the name of the table and the columns):

```
-module(admin, [Id, UserId]).
-columns([{id, "ID"}, {user_id, "user_ID"}]).
-table("admins").
```

And using 'id' atom to save the record:

```
boss_db:save_record(admins:new(id, 1)).
```